# Непослушный текст в кнопке

Tags: css

Текст отказывается слушать команду `text-decoration: none;`, с чем это связано?

```
.contactmetext {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', serif;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте еще html

Comment: @Elena исправил - a.contactmetext

Comment: **Предоставите Html код**, *возможно ошибка в том что вы указали данный параметр для блока а не ссылки*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте чтобы не было стилей для ссылки, которые перебивали бы стили для `.contactmetext`.

Потому как в примере все работает:

```css
.contactmetext {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', serif;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    
    background: #333;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="contactmetext">Lorem ipsum.</a>
```

Можно еще опробовать задать `text-decoration: none !important;`, но это крайне не желательно.

Comment: Вот так это дело выглядит в моём случае: http://imgur.com/a/Ruwqh 
Без a. - работать отказывалось.